# How docker interacts with your terminal

Tags: linux, docker, terminal

I'm curious about how dockerized processes interact with the terminal from which you run `docker run`.

From some research I done, I found that when you run a container without `-t` or `-i`, the file descriptors of the process are:

```
// the PID of the containerized process is 16198
~$ sudo ls -l /proc/16198/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:28 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:28 1 -> 'pipe:[242758]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:28 2 -> 'pipe:[242759]'
```

I see that the other ends of those pipes are of the `containerd-shim` process that spawned the containerized process. We know that once that process will write something to its STDOUT, it will show up on the terminal from which you ran `docker run`. Further, when you run a container with `-t` and look at the open FDs of the process:

```
~$ sudo ls -l /proc/17317/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:45 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:45 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:45 2 -> /dev/pts/0
```

So now the container has a pseudo-tty slave as STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR. Who has the master side of that slave? Listing the FDs of the parent `containerd-shim` we can now see that it has a `/dev/ptmx` open:

```
$ sudo ls -l /proc/17299/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:50 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:50 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:50 10 -> 'socket:[331340]'
l--------- 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:50 12 -> /run/docker/containerd/afb8b7a1573c8da16943adb6f482764bb27c0973cf4f51279db895c6c6003cff/init-stdin
l--------- 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:50 13 -> /run/docker/containerd/afb8b7a1573c8da16943adb6f482764bb27c0973cf4f51279db895c6c6003cff/init-stdin
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 18 09:50 14 -> /dev/pts/ptmx
...
```

So I suppose that the `containerd-shim` process interacts with the container process using this pseudo-terminal system. By the way, even in this case you can't interact with the process, since I didn't ran the container with `-i`.

So one question is: what difference does it make if `containerd-shim` interacts with the process using a pipe or using a pseudo-terminal subsystem?

Another question is, how do `containerd-shim` rolls this data to the terminal from which I ran `docker run`